# Spring: return xml for rest call response not as expected

Tags: spring, rest, xstream

I am trying to follow the tutorial at:
http://pfelitti87.blogspot.be/2012/07/rest-services-with-spring-3-xml-json.html

Which basically is a tutorial on how to automatically convert your spring controller response to JSON\XML. The latter uses xstream.

And my configuration is exactly the same as his (besides the packages to scan obviously).

And my JSON url looks like I'd expect, however the .xml url does not return what I'd expect.
It starts with:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult><nestedPath/>
    <nestedPathStack serialization="custom"><unserializable-parents/><vector>
<default><capacityIncrement>0</capacityIncrement><elementCount>0</elementCount>
<elementData><null/><null/><null/><null/><null/><null/><null/><null/><null/><null/></elementData></default></vector></nestedPathStack><objectName>coursesTakenForDealer</objectName>-<messageCodesResolver class="org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver"><prefix/><formatter class="org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver$Format">PREFIX_ERROR_CODE</formatter></messageCodesResolver>
```

And only contains the actual returned object towards the end.

Additionally it seems to ignore the `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlElement` annotations.

I have a name instance variable on my Person class marked as @XmlAttribute yet it is converted as:

```
<person>
    <name>Jack</name>
</person>
```

Any advice on how to resovle this\references to a better tutorial (perhaps using jaxb) would be much appreciated.

Edit:
As requested, part of my output (it does not completely fit in here). It is invoked using : `http://localhost:8080/restTestApp/interestingPeople.xml`

edit2:
The controller:

```
@Controller
public class InterestingPeopleController {


    @RequestMapping(value="interestingPeople", method = GET)
    public InterestingPeople getCoursesTakenByDealers() {   
        InterestingPeople interestingPeople;
        //some logic (service calls etc) to fill it in
        return interestingPeople;
    }
}
```

edit 3:
I was able to resolve this by adding:

```
<property name="supportedClasses">
    <list>                             
        <value>com.jackdans.model.InterestingPeople</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

to my `XStreamMarshaller` bean configuration.

Comment: `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlElement` are JAXB annotations, they don't affect XStream.  You need `@XStreamAsAttribute` for XStream.  As for the `BeanPropertyBindingResult` stuff, can you show an example of exactly what your code is returning?

Comment: I added an example of what it returns. I couldn't completely fit it in there. It just seems like a lot of boilerplate xml.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear, I meant what the Java method returns, not the XML that it gets serialized to.

Comment: Updated, and thank you for your input on the @XStreamAsAttribute